# Select web element only with title tag in selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I have a html code which inside of it there are one SVG element. inside of SVG there are many g elements which every of theme has some text and rect elements and one title tag. I want to select one of this elements from rest of them with specified title string.

I tried some approach based on find_elements_by_css_selector and select all rect elements and go back to parent element and check if the title (.text) is equal to specified text or not. But, this approach went to failed.

Another approach which I chose was find all elements based on g class item and go back to parent and then check the title of them. But, when I  tried this approach I faced with this error "StaleElementReferenceException('stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document\n\".

The simple version of my html file is like this:

```html
<g class="class1">
    <title>some specified title</title>
    <rect x="809.875" y="9" width="461.5416666666667" height="4" class="element-body"></rect>
    <rect x="809.875" y="9" width="461.5416666666667" height="4" style="fill:#000080"></rect>
    <text x="814.875" y="8" class="svg-element-number" style="font-size:11px">080</text>
    <text x="792.875" y="8" class="svg-X" style="font-size:11px">xx1</text>
    <text x="1266.4166666666667" y="8" class="svg-X" style="font-size:11px">xx2</text>
    <image href="img/reg-changed.png" x="1256.4166666666667" y="10" height="13" width="15"></image>
</g>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below line to select required element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[name()="g" and *[name()="title" and .="some specified title"]]')
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try with xpath

```
 //*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g']/*[name()='title' and text()='some specified title']
```

if you wish to access the g tag after locating the title by text use xpath axes like /parent::*

More info here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

Answer (score 0):

there is method for tagname,
if you want only 
you can use this,

```
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('title')
```